# Spatial join using FME

Tags: fme-form, spatial-join

I have two data sets, one is a polygon data set (Norwegian counties) and the other is points (roadkill incidence data). I want to do a spatial join where the points dataset inherits attributes (name/number etc) from the county they are within.

I am setting up a batch job which will be supplied with regularly updated data. The tool is FME 2015.0.

[image]

I have tried using the SpatialFilter transformer to do this using my point data as candidate data and the county data set as filter data. I have tried Contains and within filters with no luck. I only the county polygons from the passed output. Swithching around does not help much either. Still polygons.

Is there an other way to do this using FME?

Comment: Just to clarify, you are getting a polygon output even when the candidate is points data?

Comment: Yes. I can check it once more, but it surprised me somewhat based on what I read in the transformer description.

Comment: That's not the behaviour I'm getting in FME 2014. Perhaps it's a bug in your version. Check with Safe support.

Comment: Ok. Will do. Just checked and I can confirm the "anomaly".

Comment: Do you have "Use Bounding Box" set to "Yes"?  Also, I've had mixed results with the SpatialFilter.  Setting your test to "Intersects" should be fine with your filter as your polygon and your candidate as the points.

Comment: Also check the Pass Criteria and Filter Type parameters, as they could potentially cause an issue. But I too am puzzled why or how you are getting polygon output with point input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PointOnAreaOverlayer should achieve the same task if you can't get the SpatialFilter working.

Answer (score 3):

Try putting a Deaggregator transformer before the SpatialFilter. Technically the SpatialFilter is using OGC spatial relationship tests. However, these spatial relations are not defined for aggregate geometries.

So if your data is a set of aggregate features, it won't be OGC compliant, but deaggregating would solve the problem.

Alternatively use a different method like the PointOnAreaOverlayer mentioned by someone else.

For the full list of supported relationships [see this page](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/Content/Transformers/spatialrelations.htm) in the documentation.

Other geometries that aren't OGC valid for the purposes of this transformer:

- surfaces
- solids
- point clouds
- rasters