# Assign attributes from nearby line to another line in FME

Tags: fme-form

I have two polyline datasets. One is a topoligically/spatially correct road centerline (red in the image below "new"), the other is a spatially inaccurate but properly attributed road centerline (yellow - "old"). I want to get the attributes into the spatially accurate one.

I am just learning FME and would like to do it using that.
[image]

It's basically a spatial join but with a tolerance of up to about 5m . I see that there are options for point datasets ([Spatial join using FME](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143714/spatial-join-using-fme)) but I can't seem to find anything for polylines.

I found a solution based on arcmap but I prefer to use FME in this case. See [Merging and joining two line feature classes while maintaining attributes from both using ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113659/merging-and-joining-two-line-feature-classes-while-maintaining-attributes-from-b)

There's the following but it also dealing with a point dataset ([FME - Is there a transformer to snap point on point of nearest line?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144283/fme-is-there-a-transformer-to-snap-point-on-point-of-nearest-line))

Do I need to buffer the new dataset and then join the attributes of anything within the buffer and then convert this back into a line? or do I need to convert line to point and then run the above-suggested processes? or is there some simpler fme model process I can apply?

====
Based on @buddiebubba response I had the issue that he and @Mark Ireland said would happen.

I am not sure what attributes to use in the following
[image]

=== with the Azimuth Calc I don't get any matches...
[image]

See https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1XGDTNNfbMJZXZOZWRKa2lwMG8/view?usp=sharing for the fmw

=== I also tried the following which ends up with pretty much the same result. 
[image]

See https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1XGDTNNfbMJXzBKaDNWZldxNGM/view?usp=sharing for the fmw

=== the fmw works but there's still a lot of mismatch...
[image]

The sample data is in https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1XGDTNNfbMJVzI1TUdEOFg2Yzg

Comment: Are your datasets in the same coordinate system?  If not, you'll need to reproject one to match the other.  Also, can we see a screenshot of your NeighborFinder transformer?

Comment: @Fezter yes they are in same coord sys. I have added links to the fmw files and another process I tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NeighborFinder will do what you need. New = base, old = candidate. Parameters: 1 candidate to find, distance 5m. The only challenge is to prevent matching the wrong candidate at intersections. Snipping off first and last point of both the base & candidate features should do the job.

======= update 20160620
As Mark suggested adding the AzimuthCalculator should solve the wrong match problem. You need to calculate the overall bearings from both sets, find the matching lines with the NeighborFinder and then test the result based on the difference between the bearings from the matched lines. See added screenshot.

[image]
You need to iterate what variables for Distance (NeighborFinder) and difference in bearing (Tester) works the best for your data.

Comment: NeighborFinder https://www.safe.com/transformers/neighbor-finder/

Comment: @buddiebubba thanks, can you share the fmw?

Comment: @GeorgeC https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/36253197/match_lines.fmwt here you go.

Comment: @buddiebubba thanks. A lot of lines aren't matched, what settings do you think I should change. See https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1XGDTNNfbMJVzI1TUdEOFg2Yzg/view?usp=sharing for a sample dataset

Comment: @GeorgeC I need a sample of the old data as well to check.

Comment: @buddiebubba the zip file I attached has the old and new data in it.

Comment: @GeorgeC in the zip I only get the table CCRC_Road_Centerline_NEW.

Comment: @buddiebubba weird - I see them all. Anyway try https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1XGDTNNfbMJRzNJVVY2TTJTak0

Comment: @GeorgeC now I am missing the .dat files? Neither FME nor QGIS returns geometry.

Comment: This is embarrassing. So sorry @buddiebubba please see https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1XGDTNNfbMJQWFVTzFpSFNleVE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @buddiebubba were you able to have a look? I'd like to accept this answer once we get it refined.

Comment: Yeah I saw a 70% match, which is a good result for an automated process in my book. Will try to share an updated workbench today.

Comment: @buddiebubba thanks, look forward to seeing the updated workbench.

Comment: @GeorgeC the best result I get is 62%. The main reasons for mismatch are: Difference in direction (for example asset 1009862), this could be solved by the tester, + - 180 degrees. And the segments do differ so much that a match is hard to be made, let alone an automated one.

Data + workbench: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/36253197/match_lines.zip

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the NeighborFinder transformer finds the closest 'candidate' to each 'base'.

Additionally, I would try a custom transformer we have called the PolylineAnalyzer. This transformer will tell you the overall bearing of each feature. If the bearing of the features you are matching are not within (say) 5 to 10 degrees of each other then it's likely to be the wrong match.

For example, in your screenshot the vertical yellow line is closer to the horizontal red, rather than the vertical red:

[image]

NeighborFinder by itself could produce the wrong result, but the bearings would be closer to 90 degrees different, highlighting that potential issue.

Comment: -you were right the angles do matter. So I tried the Polyline Analyzer but I am not sure what values to use in here. I have attached an image to the orginal question.

Comment: @GeorgeC segment angle needs to be with 5-10 use a tester to find poor angles for between your polylines. >10 or <5 can be used.

Comment: OK. My bad. I think what you need is the AzimuthCalculator transformer (which is a component of the PolylineAnalyzer, which is why I got confused). Sorry. If you just place an AzimuthCalculator then there are no parameters and it will return the values you need.

Comment: @MarkIreland thanks, I added this but now I get no matched segments.

Comment: @GeorgeC I updated my answer with the suggestion from Mark.